# jquery: hiding contents of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m new to programming and JavaScript. I want to create a simple memory game with numbers. The program is like this, when the user click on the button, numbers will be shown in 5 seconds and after that, numbers will hide until the user click on cards. Is the code below right? I tried many codes but it didn't work

```
// {k1,...,k16} are the divs' ids and kart is div's classname
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#k1").html("2");
    $("#k2").html("3");
    $("#k3").html("1");
    $("#k4").html("3");
    $("#k5").html("5");
    $("#k6").html("6");
    $("#k7").html("1");
    $("#k8").html("6");
    $("#k9").html("4");
    $("#k10").html("7");
    $("#k11").html("8");
    $("#k12").html("8");
    $("#k13").html("5");
    $("#k14").html("7");
    $("#k15").html("2");
    $("#k16").html("4");
  });

});

function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.kart').empty();
  }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: If you want the cards to appear in 5 seconds. You want `.click(setTimeout(function…),5000)`.

Comment: You should provide the HTML in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you out: basically you want to hide the content of the div so you can do the `hide();` function then you said you will show the card for seconds then do a

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $(".kart").html();

}, 1000);
```

and use the `.show()` function.

Comment: Calling `.html()` without any parameter won't do anything. It will just return the value of the `innerHTML`

Comment: i just did that for the purpose of what his parameter would be but thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Did  you want  to do  this?

```js
//k1,k2 and... are div ids and kart is divs classname
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#k1").data("number", "2");
    $("#k2").data("number", "3");
    $("#k3").data("number", "1");
    $("#k4").data("number", "3");
    $("#k5").data("number", "5");
    $("#k6").data("number", "6");
    $("#k7").data("number", "1");
    $("#k8").data("number", "6");
    $("#k9").data("number", "4");
    $("#k10").data("number", "7");
    $("#k11").data("number", "8");
    $("#k12").data("number", "8");
    $("#k13").data("number", "5");
    $("#k14").data("number", "7");
    $("#k15").data("number", "2");
    $("#k16").data("number", "4");

    myFunction();
  });

});

function myFunction() {
  $(".kart").each(function(i, a) {
    $(a).html($(a).data("number"));
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    // if you want to use class name for selector,  you must set the class first!
    $(".kart").html("");
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="k1" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k2" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k3" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k4" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k5" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k6" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k7" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k8" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k9" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k10" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k11" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k12" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k13" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k14" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k15" class="kart"></div>
<div id="k16" class="kart"></div>
<button type="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: @nasim, you can wrap your numbers inside another element like span which has `kart` class and then, append each of these spans to different "div"s. now you are able to hide just numbers and not your div's. let me know if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Check it out again! ?